Random sums of cosine functions
I apologise in advance as I have next to no expertise in the fields to which the following question relates (and I'm unsure whether I tagged it appropriately).
Let $a_0, \cdots, a_{n-1}$ a sequence of complex numbers of modulus one, and consider the $1$-periodic function
$ f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{a_k \cos(2\pi k x)}$
(I could have taken sines or complex exponentials instead of cosines, this is just a cosmetic choice). The normalising constant $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is there to ensure that the $\mathrm{L}^2$-norm of $f$ (restricted to $[0,1]$ or seen as a function of $S^1 = \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$) be equal to $1$.
My (vague) question is the following:
What should I expect the order of magnitude the sup norm of f to be, when n is large?

The worst (or best depending on how one looks at it :) ) case scenario is of course $\sqrt{n}$, when all the $a_i$ are equal for instance.

A more precise version of this question would ask for the expectation of the sup norm when the $(a_i)$ are chosen according to the Lebesgue measure on the $n$-torus.


The thing I would be even happier to understand would be the following refinement of this question: given such a function $f$ I am given a distribution law $\mu_f$ which is a measure on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$ \mu_f(A) =  \mathrm{Leb}(\{x \in [0,1] \ | \ f(x) \in A \}.$
What should I expect this distribution $\mu_f$ to look like, when n is large and the $(a_i)$ taken at random?

Again an extreme case is when the $(a_i)s$ are equal to $1$, $f$ is almost a Dirac mass at $0$ and $\mu_f$ is also almost a Dirac mass at $0$.
I was hoping that for generic $f$ $\mu_f$ would look like a Gaussian (or something universal).

Any partial answer or reference relating to this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Googling "maximum of a random trigonometric function" led me to the following MO question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62672/random-trigonometric-polynomial (the answer by Mark Lewko talks about $\pm 1$ signs, which of course implies your question as well).

Thank you for the link. It is a bit different to the case I'm considering (the random coefficients are not restricted to have modulus 1 and follow a Gaussian law), but there is also little in the way of an answer. Also, a couple of things are unclear to me.

I don't see how the case +/- 1 implies what I'm after?
I can't find the easy heuristic justification to get to this answer, assuming it should apply to my case.


For random series, the $L^{\infty}$ norm is almost bounded by the $L^2$ norm, except for a logarithmic (in $n$) factor. A standard reference for this kind of thing is Kahane's book on random series of functions.

Thanks, I'm going to have a look. Am I likely to find information about the distribution of the function as well in this book?

A cos-metic choice

One should expect $c\sqrt{\log n}$ with a constant $c$ that can be computed.
To see the upper bound, use that (up to multiplicative constant $a(C)$ which goes to $1$ as $C\to\infty$), the maximum is obtained on a collection of $Cn$
points, equi-spaced, and Chebycheff's inequality gives you the desired estimate. The lower bound follows from a second moment computation, using a collection of $n$ equi-spaced points (as a side, note that Borell's inequality implies that
the fluctuations of the maximum are of order $1$ at most, since the pointwise variance is at most $1$).
